# Bootstrap - Popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have wanted to add some popovers to my sample page, the below code doesn't work? Ive included the CSS and bootstrap files. When you click it, nothing happens, yet if I try it on examples on bootstrap site, its all fine..

What am I missing? the carrousel works fine, so its all linked correctly?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Comment: Have you added the javascript? `$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover()`

Comment: On Bootstrap website, it says you dont need to add these as its all compiled for you..."You can use all Bootstrap plugins purely through the markup API without writing a single line of JavaScript. This is Bootstrap's first-class API and should be your first consideration when using a plugin."

Answer (score 0):

It can be several things. Since your button "data" attributes are OK, and since I cannot see your HTML source code I will try to guess:

1. Make sure that you have included jquery library in HTML
2. Make sure that you have included bootstrap popover JS in HTML
3. Make sure that you have included bootstrap tooltip JS in HTML
   (Popovers require the tooltip plugin to be included)
4. Dont forget to add this into JS "$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();"
5. And also, you cannot test to see if it's work just by double click on index page. You need localhost server in order to work (such as MAMP, WAMP, XAMP, based on what OS you are using).

If that didn't helped you, please put your example on http://jsfiddle.net/ or send URL so I can investigate where is the problem.

P.S. I'm editing answer with working example here http://bootply.com/vxw2PDRBkA
If you remove that JS code popover will stop work.

Comment: bootstrap popover.js ? I just include the bootstrap.js as thats what it only asks for? and yes I use WAMP, as i said the rest of it works, where do I get popover.js then? there is no mention of this? or in the downloads.

Comment: OK. Since you already inserted bootstrap.js that includes all JS features. So, in just before ending <body> tag, just add this:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
});
</script>
As on Bootstrap website said "For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself." That mean you need to initialize them using JS function

Comment: Take a look at this example. http://www.bootply.com/vxw2PDRBkA
If you remove that JS code popover will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Usage
Enable popovers via JavaScript:

```
$('#example').popover(options)
```

[see an exemple here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Answer (score 0):

Add "pover" to the class of the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pover" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```